# visual inheritance is currently disabled in my PocketPC project

Tags: c#

I have a pocketPC project in c# (visual studio 2005)
I want to make base form and child form from the base form
when I do that I see this:
"visual inheritance is currently disabled because the base class references a device-specific component or contains p/Invoke"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Had the same problem. Go to your base form (which is inherited) and view a class diagram. Select the base form class shape and go to properties window, click on CustomAttributes, a window comes up, just add this line in it:

```
DesktopCompatible(true)
```

and rebuild application, it should display forms fine in designer

Comment: Had to add it on all derived controls.

Comment: the xmta file must be Build action = None.